# How to pop out nested child component outside of ancestor that has overflow hidden?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

I have a sliding carousel with its overflow-x property set to hidden that contains a number of items shown 4 at a time. Within the items, there is a button that triggers an absolutely positioned pop-out menu that is longer than the carousel container and that is relative to its parent item. When the menu is visible, its full height is cut off and becomes scrollable.

What I would like is to have the pop-out menu fully visible without being cut off by the carousels overflow. Is this possible?

Ideally, I would like to find a CSS solution first before resorting to JS. The only information I can find in regards to this on the web are examples only related to parent and direct child elements and do not take into account nested child elements, so any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class='carousel'> //has overflow-x hidden
  <div class='item'> //multiple item elements
    <div class='wrapper'> //relative positioned wrapper
      <div class='pop-out'> //absolutely positioned pop out
        <div class='pop-out-list'> //list that contains multiple items which are cut off
          <div class='pop-out-item'>
          ...
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle better demonstrating this problem
https://jsfiddle.net/84p9gkru/

Answer (score 0):

just use a `z-index` property higher than `carousel` in `pop-out-list` like

```
.pop-out-list{
z-index:99999;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, I tried that but it did not work. I attached a fiddle better highlighting the problem.